# Applying mean shift to detected windows

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

currently I've implemented an algorithm to extract features out of depth images, and I want to apply mean shift clustering on all the detected windows.

How do I use openCV for that ? I understand that OpenCV has mean shift, however it seems like it's applicable on back projection of an image. Is there any other OpenCV functions that I can use to find the mode of the detection windows (maybe utilising something similar to mean shift)

Or is there any open-source mean shift codes that I can repurpose for this matter ?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV exposes a mean shift image filter, but not the general clustering algorithm. You can adapt a kernel density estimation library, such as [LibAgf](http://libagf.sourceforge.net/), for this purpose fairly easily. Mean shift is simply repeated assignment to every point of the average of all others weighted by KDE.